# In Arviz while ploting the plot_trace or plot_posterior getting the type error

Tags: python, data-science, arviz, bambi

While running the code az.plot_trace(result_final);
facing the below error
**TypeError: expected dtype object, got 'numpy.dtype[float64]'**

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError: CPUDispatcher(<function histogram at 0x00000147106C8B88>) returned a result with an error set

Can you please let me know how to solve this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, could you share more details about your problem? A minimal reproducible example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest upgrading numba to the latest version, e.g. `python3 -m pip install numba==[latest version]`. This might require a manual update to llmvite as well by doing, `python3 -m pip install --ignore-installed llvmlite`. Hope that helps!